# How to fix an Uncommented main method?

Tags: java, methods, comments, program-entry-point, sonarqube

I have been looking for this problem through google but it turns out I can not find a way to fix this problem. Actually I have a classic `main` method in which I run a job, but sonarqube keeps repeating me there is an Uncommented main method found.

Here is the code :

```
     /**
     * Main : Run MapReduce job
     * 
     * @param args
     *            arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExitManager exitManager = new ExitManager();
        // run job
        if (!runJob(args)) {
            exitManager.exit(1);
        }
    }
```

I do not see any particular problem here, so where does this problem come from ? Do you have any idea how I can fix this ?

Thanks.

Comment: This main method is UNCOMMENTED. I do not see any issue.

Comment: I do not get it, how is it uncommented there ?

Comment: Reading the answers below, it seems it's a simple misunderstanding of the word "comment". Like the OP, I took it to mean that the method should have a comment, not that it should be commented-out so that it cannot execute

Comment: @Stewart So you mean I should just add specific comments on the main method instead of commented-out it ?

Comment: No, the CheckStyle alert is saying you shouldn't have a `main()` method *at all*. Obviously this alert just doesn't apply to you.

Answer (score 8):

*Uncommented main method* is a CheckStyle warning that the `main()` method is not commented-out. You are not supposed to have debug/test `main()` methods in your code.

You can exclude your program entry point class using something like:

```
<module name="UncommentedMain">
    <property name="excludedClasses" value="\.Main$"/>
</module>
```

See also http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_misc.html#UncommentedMain

Comment: So you mean I should comment all the main method so it can not be executed ?

Comment: It depends, is the main() in question a program entry point or a debug method? If it's the entry point then you can exclude it from the checks, see my update.

Comment: I see. Where do you put those lines ? Are you using an ant file or something ?

Comment: @hacks4life You normally set these in your `*checks.xml` file. For SonarQube I believe you can set them in sonar.checkstyle.filters configuration at "Settings -> Java -> Checkstyle"

Comment: ...or if this rule really bothers you, you can even disable it from your quality profile.

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_misc.html#UncommentedMain):

> Checks for uncommented main() methods.
>
> Rationale: A `main()` method is often used for debugging purposes. When debugging is finished, 
>      developers often forget to remove the method, which changes the API and increases the size of 
>      the resulting class or JAR file. With the exception of the real program entry points, all `main()`
>      methods should be removed or commented out of the sources.

Comment: What if my program really is an entry point and I still have this warning? :)

Answer (score 2):

You can suppress the warning with @SuppressWarnings:

```
@SuppressWarnings("uncommentedmain")
public class YourClass {
    ...
```